# use async service method as factory provider in angular 10

Tags: angular, asynchronous, factory

I am developing an app with Angular 10 and I have to perform various initializations before the app is displayed to the user.

I am new to Angular and Typescript and I am trying to do this based on samples found by googling the web.

So far I have done this, which is supposed to make the app wait 10 seconds before launching, but it does not work yet.

I have created an AdminutilsService with the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AdminutilsService {

  constructor() { }

  loadCustomerConfig(): (() => Promise<boolean>) {
    return (): Promise<boolean> => {
      return new Promise<boolean>((resolve: (a: boolean) => void): void => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 10000);
      });
    };
  }

}
```

In app.module.ts, I have added:

```
import { AdminutilsService } from './adminutils.service';
export function loadCustomerConfigFactory(myAdminutilsService: AdminutilsService) {
     return () => myAdminutilsService.loadCustomerConfig();
}
```

and also in @NgModule:

```
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: loadCustomerConfigFactory,
    deps: [AdminutilsService],
    multi: true
  }],
```

Compile is done, since I have only a warning on line

```
export function loadCustomerConfigFactory(AdminutilsService: AdminutilsService) {
```

expected call-signature: 'loadCustomerConfigFactory' to have a typedef (typedef)

But when I launch the app, there is not a 10 seconds delay as expected.

Please advise.

Comment: This is the expected behavior as you are not resolving the promise your function returns. Also what do you mean by perform various initializations, you should focus on that part instead of trying to find a hacky workaround.

Comment: This is not a hacky workaround, I am just a beginner in Angular code, looking for the right syntax for handling promises. Seems someone gave me the right syntax below, will check that soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it a lot more complicated than necessary.

The following simplified code should work:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminutilsService {
  loadCustomerConfig(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 10000);
    });
  }
}
```

In app.module.ts:

```
import { AdminutilsService } from './adminutils.service';

export function loadCustomerConfigFactory(myAdminutilsService: AdminutilsService) {
  return () => myAdminutilsService.loadCustomerConfig();
}
```

I've also set up a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-npoqa2?file=src/app/app.module.ts) for demonstration. The "loading" displays for 10 seconds, until then the Angular application initializes.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works exactly as expected. I just begin with Angular and TypeScript, and syntax for promises was confusing me.

Comment: @EricMalalel perfect, glad i could help :) Could you mark the answer as accepted?